# es6 literal string concatenation as prop in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Obviously below code doesn't work, I don't know how to do it to be honest.

```
<div>                          
  <Dropdown labelName="Settings" listItems={[
    {name:'View Listing', handlerName:'view_listing'}, 
    {name:'Edit Listing', handlerName:'edit_listing'}, 
    {name:`${this.state.spaceStatus} === 'active' ? 'Deactivate Listing': 'Activate Listing'`, handlerName:'deactivate_listing'}, 
  ]}/>
</div>
```

I can do my logic out side but was trying to do it inline, not sure this is workable or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just ended the template literal token too soon. Your whole conditional operator expression should be in the `${...}`, just move the `}` to after the end of `'Activate Listing'`:

```
<div>                          
  <Dropdown labelName="Settings" listItems={[
    {name:'View Listing', handlerName:'view_listing'}, 
    {name:'Edit Listing', handlerName:'edit_listing'}, 
    {name:`${this.state.spaceStatus === 'active' ? 'Deactivate Listing': 'Activate Listing'}`, handlerName:'deactivate_listing'}, 
    // >>>---------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
  ]}/>
</div>
```